# How do you take away values?

Tags: javascript, html, numbers, subtraction

In a text adventure game I am coding with my friend, the player, goes through a hole and meets a man, who offers him/her help, but costs all the player's items, (sticks, rocks) however, I would like to know how to make the value of sticks and rocks go back to 0 after the player accepts the deal. Here is the current code:

```
<script>
var y=1 
var x=3
function stickAmount() {
    var stickNo=document.getElementById("stickNumber")
    stickNo.innerHTML="Sticks: "+y;
    y++ 
}

function rockAmount() {
    var rockNo=document.getElementById("rockNumber")
    rockNo.innerHTML="Rocks: "+x;
    x++
}

function one() {
    var newButton1 = '<button id="btnTwo" onclick="two();stickAmount();" >Pick up   
    stick</button>'; var newButton2 = '<button id="btnThree" onclick="three()">Leave it there</button>';
    document.getElementById("a").innerHTML="<p>You feel something on the ground, and you think it's a stick.</p>"+newButton1+newButton2;

    var myButton = document.getElementById('btnOne');
    myButton.onclick = four;
}

function two() {
    document.getElementById("b").innerHTML="<p>You pick up the stick. It might be useful for something.</p>";

    document.getElementById("inventory").style.display = "block";

    document.getElementById("btnThree").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("btnTwo").style.display = 'none';
}

function three() {
    document.getElementById("b").innerHTML="<p>You leave the stick on the ground and continue on.</p>";

    document.getElementById("btnTwo").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("btnThree").style.display = 'none';
}

function four() {
    var newButton1 = '<button id="btnFour" onclick="five();stickAmount();rockAmount();" >Take the items</button>'; 
    var newButton2 = '<button id="btnFive" onclick="six()">Leave them</button>';
    document.getElementById("c").innerHTML="<p>You feel a stick stuck to the wall with something like honey. Next to it is a few rocks.</p>"+newButton1+newButton2;

    var myButton = document.getElementById("btnOne")
    myButton.onclick = seven;
}

function five() {
    document.getElementById("d").innerHTML="<p>You grab the stick and the rocks. Some of the sticky substance rubs off on your hand.</p>";

    document.getElementById("rockNumber").style.display = "block";

    document.getElementById("btnFive").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("btnFour").style.display = 'none';
}

function six() {
    document.getElementById("d").innerHTML="<p>You leave the stick and rocks, but some of the sticky substance still rubs off on your hand.</p>";

    document.getElementById("btnFive").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("btnFour").style.display = 'none';
}

function seven() {
    var newButton1 = '<button id="btnSix" onclick="eight()" >Climb through</button>'; 
    var newButton2 = '<button id="btnSeven" onclick="nine()">Ignore it</button>';
    document.getElementById("e").innerHTML="<p>As you feel around the cave you find a hole, it seems just big enough for you to climb through.</p>"+newButton1+newButton2;
}

function eight() {
    document.getElementById("f").innerHTML="<p>The hole leads to a room with small torches to light it up, and you jump when you hear a voice in the corner.</p>";

    document.getElementById("conversations").style.display='block';

    var newButton1 = '<button id="btnEight" onclick="ten()">Trust him</button>';

    document.getElementById("ii").innerHTML="<p><strong>Man in corner:</strong> I think I can help you see the cave, but my work isn't free. It will cost all your items.  
</p>"+newButton1;

    document.getElementById("btnSix").style.display='none';
    document.getElementById("btnSeven").style.display='none';
}

function nine() {
    document.getElementById("f").innerHTML="<p>You walk right past the hole and feel a flashlight on the floor, and you bend over to pick it up. You can now see the cave.</p>";

    document.getElementById("btnSix").style.display='none';
    document.getElementById("btnSeven").style.display='none';

    var elem = document.getElementById("btnOne");
    if (elem.innerHTML=="Feel around the cave") {
        elem.innerHTML = "Look around the cave";
    } else {
        elem.innerHTML = "Feel around the cave";
    }
}

function ten() {
    document.getElementById("g").innerHTML="The man created you a torch. Now you can see around the cave."

    var elem = document.getElementById("btnOne");
    if (elem.innerHTML=="Feel around the cave") {
        elem.innerHTML = "Look around the cave";
    } else {
        elem.innerHTML = "Feel around the cave";
    }

    document.getElementById("btnEight").style.display='none';
}
</script>


<div style="margin-left:15px; width:200px; margin-top:100px;">
    <button id="btnOne" onclick="one()">Feel around the cave</button>
</div>

<div id="entire" style="margin-left:250px; margin-top:-19px; width:200px; height:400px;">
    <div id="g"></div>
    <div id="f"></div>
    <div id="e"></div>
    <div id="d"></div>
    <div id="c"></div>
    <div id="b"></div>
    <div id="a"></div>
</div>

<div style="height:400px;">
    <div id="inventory" style="margin-left:550px; width:100px; height:100px; margin-top:-400px; border: 1px solid #ffffff; display:none;">
        <div id="stickNumber" style="margin-left:10px; margin-top:10px;"></div>
        <div id="rockNumber" style="margin-left:10px; display:none;"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="conversations" style="height:400px; margin-left:690px; width:200px; margin-top:-400px; display:none;">
    <div id="ii"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're keeping track of sticks and rocks by using the variable x and y. Unless I am completely missing something simply set those back to 0.

```
x=0;
y=0;
```

If that works out, I recommend you modify the variable from x and y to something more readable. Say, sticks and rocks :)

So your function would look like as follows:

```
function ten()
{
x=0;
y=0;

document.getElementById("g").innerHTML="The man created you a torch. Now you can see 
around the cave."

var elem = document.getElementById("btnOne");
if (elem.innerHTML=="Feel around the cave") elem.innerHTML = "Look around the cave";
else elem.innerHTML = "Feel around the cave";

document.getElementById("btnEight").style.display='none';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

like this:?

```
if (trusted){
sticks=0;
rocks=0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

thy this:?

```
sticks=0;
rocks=0;
```

these variables make more sense.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to be fancy, you can always do this:
    sticks=sticks-sticks;
    rocks=rocks-rocks;
That doesn't work on all programming languages, and it's been a while since I programmed with JavaScript